# File in trash not syncing with other devices

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have a program that systematically downloads new google photos and put them in the trash can. 
After the download the files are placed in the trash for 60 days before being deleted by google. I'm using the google drive api V3.

When i put a file in trash by changing the file properties, the file is placed in the trash can but on my connected devices there still in the google photos folder.
I'm putting the file in the trash can using following c# code:

```
var newContent = new File

{
     Trashed = true
};

service.Files.Update(newContent, photofile.Id).Execute();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What google photos folder?

Comment: The google folders on all my mobile devices. In the web application the picture is in the trash but on my devices it stays in the google folder.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.   You have tagged this question Google-drive-api and are you trying to delete them from your google drive? Your code looks like an update to Google-drive-api.    Google Photos is another api that does not have a delete feature. Can you please edit your question and be a bit more clear as to what you are doing.    If your issue is with a mobile device then i think you have tagged this totally wrong and should post the delete code on the device instead.

Comment: This issue is not relevant anymore because the link between google drive and photos is cut since july '19